# Application not saving png file on phone - unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a camera app on unity for learning purpose. I followed two tutorial and got my cam running Now here is a code that I found on stack overflow, The issue is its not saving the output on phone.

```
public void Pic()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
    }

    IEnumerator TakePhoto()  // Start this Coroutine on some button click
    {

        // NOTE - you almost certainly have to do this here:

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(backCam.width, backCam.height);
        photo.SetPixels(backCam.GetPixels());
        photo.Apply();

        //Encode to a PNG
        byte[] bytes = photo.EncodeToPNG();
        //Write out the PNG. Of course you have to substitute your_path for something sensible
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "photo.png", bytes);
    }
```

I have attached `Pic()` to a button.

I am just learning these so might be making some stupid mistake.

Comment: Do you know what the bytes array length is and what application.dataPath is?

Comment: `Application.dataPath` would be be the path of game folder that unity creates. And byte array length can be calculated. But why?

Comment: did you see my answer? best pracrice is using persistentDataPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be /photo.png, otherwise you are just appending a filename to foldername

You should also consider switching to persistentDataPath and validating it for file io (checking if it exists is a good practice)

Comment: yes adding the `persistentDataPath` saved the image in package folder. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Paths you should always use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) instead of direct `string` concatenation

```
Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "photo.png")
```

It is also possible that the folder or file simply don't exist yet so you could check that and create them in that case before writing

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "photo.png");

if (!Directory.Exists(Application.dataPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.dataPath);
}

if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.Create(filePath);
}

//Write out the PNG. Of course you have to substitute your_path for something sensible
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
```

Comment: If I use `Application.persistentDataPath` then it saves the image in package folder of the app. But if do even this `"/Home/Phone/cam1"` (which is the path on phone) it does not save the image. I created the folder cam1 in my phone for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a slash before your file name.

```
File.WriteAllBytes($"{Application.dataPath}/photo.png", bytes);
```